# Adding grid-lines to jpgraph whilst also having an alternating background?

Tags: php, graph, jpgraph

Is it possible to add (white) grid lines to a graph made from jpgraph, whilst also having an alternating background with it? I have the alternating background but I have no idea how to add the grid lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using flot instead of jpgraph.